# cannot assign a value of 'gym info' to a value of type ' strings' what is the issue?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

getting an issue " cannot assign a value of 'gym info' to a value of type ' strings'

```
var gyms:[gymInfo] = [gymInfo(name: "Cubo Fitness", location: "Bangalore", image: "FERRARI"), gymInfo(name: "Snap Fitness", location: "Bangalore", image: "LAMBORGHINI"), gymInfo(name: "Gold's Gym", location: "Bangalore", image: "LANDROVER")]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.gyms.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
    indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    let gym = gyms[indexPath.row]
    cell.gymNameLabel.text = gym.name
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: gym.image)
    cell.gymCityLabel.text = gym.location
    return cell }
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: can you post that `gymInfo` data structure code

Comment: @Lamour it is a custom class with three string variables in the init

Comment: what line is not working? sounds good for me

Comment: You have not provided enough information, and your description is confused. I bet the error is "cannot assign a value of 'gymInfo' to a value of type 'String' (`gymInfo` with no space, and type `String`, with a capital letter and no trailing "s" at the end.) Details matter when describing errors. Get it exactly right, and show us which line is giving you this error.

Comment: BTW, type names should start with an upper case letter in Swift, so you should refactor your project to change `gymInfo` to `GymInfo`. This is not the cause of your problem, but it is a strong naming convention in Swift that you should follow.

Comment: the error occurs in all the cell. lines @DuncanC
<"import UIKit

class gymInfo {
    var name:String = ""
    var location:String = ""
    var image:String = ""
    
    init(name:String, location:String, image:String ) {
    self.name = name
    self.location = location
    self.image = image
    }
}">

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that somehow it dosnt know about the type of the gymInfo Model. Try to set at the Line vor getting the model an `as! gymInfo` and check what is happening.

The other problem i have is your cell. Could it be, that you have to set an optional to the label settings? Or how does the cell look like?